# Spring MVC Session Attribute

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

Hello I've got a problem with Session Attribute

I've 2 Controller Class

First Class (User)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("users")
@SessionAttributes("activeuser")
public class UserController {

    ....

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String  loginUser(HttpServletRequest request,Model model, @ModelAttribute("userlogininfo") User loginuser,
            BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
        User activeuser = userService.checkuserlogin(loginuser.getUsername(), loginuser.getPassword());

        if (activeuser!=null) {
            request.getSession().setAttribute("activeuser", activeuser);
            return "redirect:/home";
        } else
            return "redirect:/index";


    }
```

Second Class(bank)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("banka")
@SessionAttributes("activeuser")
public class BankController {
....
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveBanka(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("banka") Banka banka, BindingResult result,
            SessionStatus status) {

        User user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("activeuser");

        banka.setUser(user);
        bankService.insert(banka);
        return "redirect:/home";
    }


}
```

Second Class is return null value from "(User) request.getSession().getAttribute("activeuser")"

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Assuming if session is active when /save method is received by BankController, you should normally get the "activeuser" from session.

To use the attributes defined in @SessionAttributes, try using 
public String saveBanka(...@ModelAttribute("activeuser") User user) and you should get the session attribute

Comment: Make sure your session object is Serializable.

Answer (score 1):

Add your attribute to model (instead of `request.getSession().setAttribute("activeuser", activeuser);`)

```
model.addAttribute("activeuser", activeuser);
```

Make sure activeuser is Serializable.

Comment: The OP is using session and not the request.

Comment: I believe the redirect: prefix will generate a 302 redirect http response and session will be created, so getting the session attribute into the redirected handler must get the session attribute.

Comment: @tsolakp  He is obtaining session from request `request.getSession().setAttribute("activeuser", activeuser);`
Request is dead after redirect, does not survive.

Comment: Does not matter different request can give the same session. That's the point of the session: to be the same in between requests (either with forward or redirect).

Comment: That would be true if he obtains it direct from HttpSession.